# Selenium can't click the dropdown menu

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate the scraping process for this page: https://www.immobilienscout24.de/

But I am having trouble with this dropdown menu:

[image]

The code for that part is:

```
apart_or_house = Select(driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'oss-rent'))
apart_or_house.select_by_index(2)
```

But I keep getting this error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\Users\Zemmente\Documents\Python\google maps
> scraper\test_scraping.py", line 41, in 
> apart_or_house.select_by_index(2)   File "C:\Users\Zemmente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py",
> line 98, in select_by_index
> self._set_selected(opt)   File "C:\Users\Zemmente\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py",
> line 213, in _set_selected
> raise NotImplementedError("You may not select a disabled option") NotImplementedError: You may not select a disabled option

What could be the problem, beacuse the left dropdown menu is working?

P.S. If neede here is the entire code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select, WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

URL = "https://www.immobilienscout24.de/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)

# Wait for the page to load
time.sleep(4)

# Accepting cookies (if they appear)
try:
    def get_shadow_root(element):
        return driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)

    shadow_host = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'usercentrics-root')
    button = get_shadow_root(shadow_host).find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-testid=uc-accept-all-button]')
    button.click()
except:
    print("Accept cookies not found.")

# City name
city_inputs = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="oss-location"]')))
city_input = [element for element in city_inputs if element.is_displayed()][0]
city_input.click()
city_input.send_keys(input('Enter the city name you want to search for: '))
time.sleep(1)
city_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

# Buying, renting or building
while True:
    buying_or_renting_inputs = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="oss-form"]/article/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/select')))
    buying_or_renting_input = [element for element in buying_or_renting_inputs if element.is_displayed()][0]
    options = int(input('Enter the number of one of the options: 0-Rent, 1-Buying, 2-Building: '))
    if options < 0 or options > 2:
        options = int(input('Enter the number of one of the options: 0-Rent, 1-Buying, 2-Building: '))
    else:
        select_buy_or_rent = Select(buying_or_renting_input).select_by_index(options)
        break

# Map options to corresponding names
options_mapping = {
    0: 'oss-rent',
    1: 'oss-buy',
    2: 'oss-build'
}

# Get the corresponding name based on user input
selected_option_name = options_mapping.get(options)

# Update Apartmanent or house variable dynamically
apart_or_house = driver.find_element(By.NAME, selected_option_name)
options_2 = Select(apart_or_house).select_by_index(0)

# Search for the results
search_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="oss-form"]/article/div/div[3]/button')
search_button.click()

# Handle captcha
captcha = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'geetest_radar_tip')))
captcha.click()

# Wait for the results to load
time.sleep(5)

page_source = driver.page_source

driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "html.parser")
```

Answer (score 1):

when you change the value in the left dropDown then the right dropDown changes also.

So for every option in the left you have an element with different name in the right

```
Mieten(0)-->oss-rent , Kaufen(1)--->oss-buy , Bauen(2)--->oss-build
```

for example change your code to:

```
a={
    0:'oss-rent',
    1:'oss-buy',
    2:'oss-build',
}
index=1#Kaufen
buying_or_renting_inputs = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="oss-form"]/article/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/select')))
buying_or_renting_input = [element for element in buying_or_renting_inputs if element.is_displayed()][0]
select_buy_or_rent = Select(buying_or_renting_input)
select_buy_or_rent.select_by_index(index)
time.sleep(4)

apart_or_house_inputs = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.NAME, a[index])))
apart_or_house_input = [element for element in apart_or_house_inputs if element.is_displayed()][0]
select_apart_or_house = Select(apart_or_house_input)
options=select_apart_or_house.options
for i in range(len(options)):
    select_apart_or_house.select_by_index(i)
    time.sleep(4)
```

Comment: Indeed that works. I have implemented your logic into my code (see my original post above). But I want after the user enters any of those 3 options from the left dropdown menu to choose any of the options from the right dropdown menu. Because with this new code if you put the index to be 1 or 2 in the variable apart_or_house you will get an error.